# Tiny Tiny RSS (localhost) + RSS Bridge (localhost)

Tags: docker, rss, rss-reader

TinyTinyRSS: http://localhost:181
RSS Bridge: http://localhost:10

[both working on docker containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpTp4.png)

After I add RSS Bridge feed to TTS (not matter atom/html etc), TTS showing me:
"Requested URL failed extended validation."

What I'm supposed to do with this?
I read everything possible related matter and I'm not even close solution. I spend like 5 hours fruitless.
Tried everything from Google search. Even if there was an answer, I don't understand it at all. I need only to put this to work and I will be happy and need nothing else.